# How to configure and initialize a Backbone collection with models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have this Backbone collection:

```
App.Collection.Pieces = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: App.Model.Piece,
  initialize: function(models, options) {
    this.color = options.color;
    king = new this.model({
      color: this.color
    });
    this.add(king);
    console.log(this.models[0]); // the `king` model is logged
    }
});
```

The `initialize` function seems to create and add the `king` model just fine. But in another file, I instantiate the collection and log the results:

```
this.white = new App.Collection.Pieces([], { color: 'white' });
console.log(this.white.models[0]); // `undefined` is logged
```

Here, it seems as if nothing is added. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collection is doing exactly what you're telling it to: it is creating a collection without any models.

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-constructor):

> **constructor / initialize** `new Backbone.Collection([models], [options])`
>
> When creating a Collection, you may choose to pass in the initial array of **models**.

The `[models]` notation means that `models` is optional but you're passing an array as the initial model set, an empty array but an array nonetheless. If you have a look at [the source](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.1.0/backbone.js#L595), things will be clearer:

```
var Collection = Backbone.Collection = function(models, options) {
  //...
  this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
  if (models) this.reset(models, _.extend({silent: true}, options));
};
```

so you see that first the `initialize` method is called and then [`reset`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset) is called to apply the initial model set. An empty array is truthy so you end up doing a `this.white.reset([])` to erase the `king` you added.

If you don't pass the optional `models` argument then things will work out better for you:

```
this.white = new App.Collection.Pieces(null, { color: 'white' });
```

Alternatively, if you always wanted a king, you could override `reset` on the collection to make sure the king is there.